# 面 and 顔 difference?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, nouns

There are two words for face or is there a slight difference?

Comment: Where did you see that 覚 means face? How familiar are you with Japanese/kanji?

Comment: Maybe you could ask about 顔, 面, and 顔面.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about the words「おもて」and「かお」, or the kanji「顔」and「面」? Kanji are not words, they're representations of words/morphemes. @snailboat's last example「顔面」represents another set of morphemes altogether (「がん」+「め​ん」), so if you were asking about the kanji then those morphemes also require explanation.

Answer (score 7):

顔【かお】 is the primary word for *face* (of animal/human). You should be using this word in most situations.

面 read as **つら** is an uncommon slangy/rough word that is mainly used in dirty conversations and derogatory idioms such as [どの面下げて](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE%E9%9D%A2%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%92%E3%81%A6), [面の顔が厚い](http://jisho.org/word/%E9%9D%A2%E3%81%AE%E7%9A%AE%E3%81%8C%E5%8E%9A%E3%81%84). Although some fixed phrases like [しかめっ面](http://jisho.org/word/%E9%A1%B0%E3%82%81%E9%9D%A2) and [泣きっ面に蜂](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%B3%A3%E3%81%8D%E9%9D%A2%E3%81%AB%E8%9C%82) are safe in ordinary conversations, you should not use 面 as a generic noun unless you intentionally want to offend someone.

面 read as **おもて** also means *face* or *front*, but this is a fairly literary and/or old word. You'll see this only in samurai dramas and stiff novels.

Standalone 面 read as **めん** (on-reading) is even rarer, and is used only in a few uncommon set phrases such as [面を通す](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/218070/meaning/m0u/). 面 read as めん also means *mask* (e.g. Noh mask) or *surface*. Of course 面 appears in many Sino-Japanese compounds such as 海面, 画面, 水面, etc.

Comment: There's also 面持ち with 面 read おも, which I think is not uncommon in novels and such.

Comment: Thank you, but I left that out because I thought おも is not a standalone word.

Comment: The めん reading also appears in the "Kamen" (仮面) part of the Kamen Rider TV show's original title (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamen_Rider)