# How to pronounce 面?

Tags: readings, multiple-readings

For example in the phrase "物の面", how would you *commonly* pronounce 面?
I see three possibilities: めん、つら、おも. Which one (or ones) are commonly used?

Example sentence: "人の手の指先の内側にある、多くの細い線からできている模様。また、その模様が物の面についたあと。" (指紋の定義)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57940/5010 But what is 物の面 supposed to mean? I haven't seen such a combination before. In this case, it's difficult to determine the reading without knowing the meaning.

Comment: I've added an example sentence, which should make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, 面 is read **めん** because it means "surface (of a thing)".

As for when to use the other readings, see: [面 and 顔 difference?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57940/5010)

Comment: Phew, then I was right all this time... (^^;)